# How to center PDF content in embed?

Tags: pdf, embed

I have a PDF file embed inside my web page. My HTML is:

```
<embed src="http://znaci.net/zb/4_1_19.pdf">
```

My CSS is:

```
embed {
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
}
```

Now I have a situation like this:

[image]

But I need this:

[image]

Is there a way to center a PDF content in embed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the embedded object in the `embed` tag. However, with [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf), you can exercise some control over the displayed PDF.

Here I have scaled the PDF to fit an `iframe`, with `view=FitH`.

```html
<iframe 
    src="http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#page=1&view=FitH" 
    width="500" height="600">
</iframe>
```

There are other ways you can control zoom and scroll position. Please refer to linked document for more info.

Comment: thanks, this solved me one half of the problem.

Comment: What's the other half @DamanDaman?

Comment: I need to zoom it also, if it is possible (I haven't read linked documentation yet).

Comment: It's possible. `http://path.to/file.pdf#zoom=75`. The document contains all the possible parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your patience man. However, I have read the documentation, but zoom still doesn't seems to work :( It always shows the same size.